# AppCode + swift - no code completion and no quick documentation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, appcode

Do anyone know how to enable code completion and quick documentation in **AppCode**(3.1.1) for **swift**?
I have updated Xcode I've downloaded documentation in Xcode preferences. 
I set correct path to Xcode in my AppCode but still I got no support in AppCode regarding to completion and quick documentation.
This support is in XCode but I am java dev so for me better thing is to use Jetbrains tool instead of using Apple one.

Project that I've opened in AppCode was created in XCode.
I've downloaded this documentation in XCode.
[image]

I've searched a lot in the net but there are only slogans about features of AppCode

`can do that this, is doing this and that`

Only one thing related to path to XCode I found in this property
[image]

but none of those I can see... I believe that I haven't enabled it yet.

For me AppCode is more user friently tool because like I said I am used to Intellij for Java development and I am trying to use this tool because it is quicker for me to work with sth that I've used to than sth that is completly new for me(conceptually - XCode).

Do you have any advices about that?

Comment: Ok, but why Jetbrains advertise product as a tool equal to XCode or better? Maybe someone know some hints, especially from AppCode community.

Comment: I agree marketing is one of the keys to the success in real business, but I am not hater of Apple or Jetbrains. I aksed question regarding to specified tool not for express my hate or sth like that to other competetive one. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked my quesetion to AppCode support. They responded:

> Rafal,   Your configuration seems correct.   Please see comments
>   below: 1) regarding code completion in Swift - we have part of work
>   done in that area, and part of tasks still in progress. Can you share
>   a code snippet where you experience issues with completion? 2)
>   regarding quick documentation - this feature is not yet ready for
>   Swift. You can track its progress [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11352).

This mean that I can not expect from AppCode features that was advertised in terms of swift language.

Comment: I'm testing version 3.2 and autocomplete works only sometimes (so no change). I won't upgrade, unless forced to do so, until they fix this. Still, on November they're moving to a subscription model, at which point I think we won't have a choice but to always pay for their products. If it works anything like Adobe, they will disable Appcode if you don't pay on a monthly basis. Good thing about iOS, though, is you can always go back to Xcode, which is free.

Comment: Don't you think the font size of Xcode error message is tooo tiny??

Comment: Can't this be changed?